# How do I fix stripped bolt holes in wood?

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I have a wood futon that is assembled with threaded bolts screwing into holes in the wood that are threaded.  Over time the threading in the wood has worn and the bolts just slide in and out.  I've found plenty of info online on dealing with similar situations for screws, but nothing about bolts.

What are my options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the threads are in metal, then you can replace the threads. What you're looking for is called a T-nut and should be available at any hardware store. Take a bolt with you to get the right size.

[image]

If the threads are in the wood, a simple option is to just take the bolt to a hardware store and buy a bigger bolt. T-nuts are also a good option if a bigger bolt isn't practical, but you will also need new bolts because you will not find T-nuts that match the threading of your current bolts.